# How can I package a program compiled from source to easily install on similar machines

Tags: ubuntu, debian, packaging, apt

I compiled php5 from source (for Ubuntu) so that I could work with pthreads, and now I need to copy that install to other virtual machines. I compiled it with pretty much all the same options as come by default when installing the official repo package, and install the package first to resolve any dependencies. They are all based on the same image, so I don't need to worry about changes in architecture or anything. I'm automating the install with opscode chef. The options I am guessing are available are

1. Zip compiled source folder from the working machine, unzip it on the target, and `make install` it
2. Package it as a .deb somehow, copy the .deb to the target machine and install
3. Package it as a .deb somehow, set up a single-version/single-package repository on the chef server, modify the target's apt sources, and install php with apt
4. Other

Are options 2 and 3 feasible? Difficult? If feasible and relatively easy, how is it done? Is there another good option?

All of the research I've found is about more complex cases, worrying about maintaining packages, different architectures, and making the repository public. I only need it to work internally.

---

Edit: checkinstall works for now, though it isn't ideal since I have to manually install the dependencies before using `dpkg -i`. If there is a better way, let me know

Comment: When you want to package a complex software system such as php5 (with modules later on I guess), best you look at the official packages. When you understand the files in /debian there you can substitute the sources from the official package with yours and get the job done more easily. There is a Ubuntu packaging guide around for getting started with packaging. For option 3) you probably want to use some tool to setup the repository, as getting the meta file with dpkg-scanpackages and co is a bit confusing.

Comment: Yes, checkinstall lacks dependencies. You can provide them building a fake package with equivs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checkinstall package is made exactly for this purpose. You build your package and instead of running make install, you run checkinstall. More info at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall